# Is changes of object passed to another object takes place within first object too?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Game() {
    this.player = new Component();
    this.renderer = new Renderer(this.player);
}
function Renderer(player) {
    this.player = player;
    this.player.number = 4;
}
var game = new Game();
```

Can I get a value of variable (4) "number" in that way: `game.player.number`?

Comment: I think this may help to understand that http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/

Comment: Yes. Objects are passed by references. So when you do, `this.player = player`, player's reference is assigned and not entire object is copied

Comment: @Rajesh So every change in object in one place is 'copied' to all places where this object occur?

Comment: No. When you assign an object to some key/variable, object's reference is copied and not entire object. So when you change something in object, since all other variable/keys are still pointing to same reference, even they will get updates.

Comment: If you wish to copy object and not reference, following link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rajesh I have one more question - Did that work in this way with arrays too? Arrays have a one reference in a program?

Comment: Yes. Ever arrays are objects so yes they will have same behavior.

Comment: @Rajesh And simple variables too?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. You can edit the contents of an object and that will reflect in the original object, but if you try to overwrite an entire object (the reference of it), you can't.

You can view an example in this jsfiddle (select Run top left):
https://jsfiddle.net/kcx61hye/34/

```
var player = {number:1};
var player2 = {number:2};
function Renderer(player) {
    this.player = player;
    this.player.number = 4;
}
function Renderer2(player) {
    this.player=player2;
}
document.write(player.number); //Outputs 1
Renderer(player);
document.write(player.number); //Outputs 4, so object is modified
Renderer(player2);
document.write(player.number); //outputs 4, so no modification
```